# Bukkit command repeats itself?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I have coded a Bukkit plugin with no errors, but in game it has a problem.

Whenever the command is used, it does not do what it is supposed to do. Instead, it sends me a bold message saying what I typed, `/leaving`.

Here is my code:

```
public class SeeYouSoon extends JavaPlugin{

// Start
@Override
public void onEnable(){
}

@Override 
public void onDisable() {
}

//Commands



public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String[] args){
    if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("leaving")){
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.RED + player.getName() + ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + ChatColor.ITALIC + " is about to leave the server. Please say your goodbyes!");
        Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(this, new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //Run your function or change stuff here.
               player.kickPlayer(ChatColor.RED + "Kicked:" + ChatColor.WHITE + " You requested to leave.");
            }
        }, 20 * 30);// There are 20 ticks in one second so we can just multiply seconds by 20.
    }
    return false;

}
}
```

The plugin.yml Is what I expect the problem is. Here is the plugin.yml:

```
name: SeeYouSoon
main: me.mark.SeeYouSoon
version: 1.0
commands:
   leaving:
      description: Announce your leave
```

Comment: Please include a better problem description and the actual responsible code

Comment: @jojodmo Now the command doesn't do anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, the `onCommand()` method format in `JavaPlugin` is:

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args){
```

Your next reason as to why this happens is because you don't [`return true`](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Plugin_Tutorial?cookieSetup=true#The_onCommand.28.29_Method) after you act upon the command. For example, you should use:

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args){
    if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("leaving")){
        //your code
        return true;
    }
}
```

So, your final code should look like this:

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String[] args){
    if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("leaving")){
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.RED + player.getName() + ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + ChatColor.ITALIC + " is about to leave the server. Please say your goodbyes!");
        Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(this, new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               player.kickPlayer(ChatColor.RED + "Kicked:" + ChatColor.WHITE + " You requested to leave.");
            }
        }, 20 * 30);
        return true;
    }
    return false;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not safely casting to a player:

```
Player player = (Player)sender;
```

While that is correct java, this can cause errors. Make sure the sender is actually a player before casting.

```
if (!sender instanceof Player)
{
    sender.sendMessage("Some error message");
    return true;
}
// Now you can cast to a player and continue with your code.
```